# Filter and limit with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to apply a limit and a filter to my AngularJS loop, but the filter is not working on the entire list, only on the limited list...

I have 100 agreements and I want to show only 20, but I want to add a filter to search on the other 90 agreements...

**Edit #2  :**

```js
    app.controller("AgreementsController", function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.agreements = [];
      $http.get('/api/agreement').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.limit = data.limit;
        data.agreements.forEach( function(agr){
          $scope.agreements.push(agr);
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="agreement in agreements | filter:search | limitTo:5">
      <td>{{agreement.number}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit #3 :

[image: My data model]

Answer (score 1):

I think what u written is correct only..may be problem is somewhere else

```
<tr ng-repeat="agreement in agreements | filter:search | limitTo:20">
```

just check your input search term properly binded or not...

Comment: check ur get method data in console...in which format its coming

Comment: I hope ur doing well only..I can't able to find what is mistake.

Comment: can u post ur data model

Answer (score 0):

This HTML code you showed looks good so the problem could be on your input perhaps. This does the trick:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="agreement in agreements | filter:search | limitTo:20">
        <td>{{agreement}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11319/)

Comment: I already have my input see edit #1 ;) An int? It doesn't work with an object?

Comment: @tonymx227 Not sure I see the difference, my updated fiddle has an array of objects, is that not what you need?

Comment: @tonymx227 Sounds like you have a different issue than in the original question.. now the `agreements` array is not updated ? or... ? Can you say exactly what's not working ?

Comment: The filter is still on the limited list... Not on the entire list of agreements..

Comment: Look here, http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11323/ The button adds elements to the list and the view updates automatically. Are you sure you're adding correct elements to `agreements` ?

Comment: In my `data` I just get the result of the JSON object... So yes I'm adding correct elements to agreements... If I delete the `filter` and the `limit` I see the entire list of agreements in my view...